# Test Azure IotHub metrics collector in the simulator iot edge device

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

### Problem

Azure IotHub metrics collector for Iot edge devices a very interesting feature that I am trying to implement and especially the option 2 that goes through IotMessage, so publishing a Device to Cloud message with the metrics data. So, I read the official documentation about the subject, and I got stuck at the very beginning in the architecture.

### Context

In an existing IotHub, I already have some edge modules, so I added the `metrics-collector` module, and set up the routing as suggested in the documentation. The module starts correctly but can't fetch logs from `edgeHub` nor from `edgeAgent` (which is normal because `edgehubdev` doesn't start an `edgeAgent` module). Also, when exposing the 9600 port to a local port I was able to retrieve the metrics in my host machine in the localhost:9600/metrics endpoint, so I though I could set it up in the `MetricsEndpointsCSV` property but that doesn't help.

### Question

How do you guys manage to test and end-to-end metrics retrieval through the simular (locally) ?
PS: I know that there are still some missing architecture blocks that I need to create ( event hub + function apps ), but the metrics messages are not yet arriving to iot hub.

### logs from edgeHubDev

```
metricsCollector       | [2021-11-08 14:47:03.044 INF] Starting periodic operation Scrape and Upload Metrics...
metricsCollector       | [2021-11-08 14:47:03.045 INF] Scraping endpoint http://127.0.0.1:9600/metrics
metricsCollector       | [2021-11-08 14:47:03.046 ERR] Error scraping endpoint http://127.0.0.1:9600/metrics - System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Connection refused
metricsCollector       |  ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (111): Connection refused
metricsCollector       |    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
metricsCollector       |    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
metricsCollector       |    at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
metricsCollector       |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean allowHttp2, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
metricsCollector       |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
metricsCollector       |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
metricsCollector       |    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
metricsCollector       |    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
metricsCollector       |    at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
metricsCollector       |    at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Edge.Azure.Monitor.MetricsScraper.ScrapeEndpoint(String endpoint, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in /mnt/vss/_work/1/s/edge-modules/azure-monitor/src/MetricsScraper.cs:line 72
```

**EDIT
Fun Fact: It works in azure not in my machine =D**

### References

Documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/iot-edge/how-to-collect-and-transport-metrics?view=iotedge-2020-11&tabs=iothub#next-steps

Azure sample: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/iotedge-logging-and-monitoring-solution

Comment: You mentioned this worked in an Azure VM using iotedgehubdev right? In your local machine did you check the proxy configuration? "by setting the NO_PROXY environment variable."

Comment: no I meant it worked when deployed to an edge device using iotedge, I will give the NO_PROXY env var a try, what value should it has ? `true` ?

Comment: Set NO_PROXY value to a comma-separated list of hostnames that should be excluded. Use module names for hostnames. For example: edgeHub,edgeAgent,myCustomModule.

Comment: yes but, the iotedgehubdev doesn't run an edgeAgent container

Answer (score 2):

Try setting the following value `http://edgeHubDev:9600/metrics` in the metrics collector configuration for `MetricsEndpointsCSV`